# How does Python know the difference between a list and an index?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have the following code:

```
var1 = "executable"[2]
var2 = [2]
```

How does the program know var1 is not a string followed by a list and var2 is a list and not an index?

Comment: how do *you* know? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just the syntax of the language. If the square brackets have an indexable object on the left, then python treats it as an index. If the square brackets are standalone, as with var2, it doesn't, it creates a new list instead.

Comment: Not to mention that "string list" can't have any other reasonable meaning...you can't just put objects next to each other.